# Why is a reboot not always a reboot proper? Or: Why must I sometimes reboot twice for effect?

Tags: startup, restart

This is a question posed of curiosity, not because the issue troubles me greatly.

At work, I have a OneLink dock for my ThinkPad. It attached ethernet, a mouse and an additional screen. During my typical workday, all will work and my day will conclude with me unplugging the machine and closing the lid, making it suspend.

The next morning, I will show up often not having used the machine since work the previous day, open the lid and plug it in. For some reason, the ethernet will then not connect properly. I'll reboot, and gain internet access. The external mouse will then not work. I'll reboot again and gain both internet access and a functional mouse.

This behavior puzzles me and leads me to my question: **Why are the two reboots not equivalent?**

Is something kept over from a first reboot, but forgotten during the second? Or vice versa? Or ...?

Comment: Does it work right if you plug the dock in first, before waking the computer from suspend by opening the lid?

Comment: I have a script that reinitializes network card and mouse when resuming from suspend. If you are interested I can post it later.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly common for drivers to be in an unstable state returning from suspend. I've seen this numerous times with numerous operating systems. A workaround that should work consistently is to save your work, shut down the system and unplug it (leaving it connected to the dock) and replug and power on the system in the morning. Since we are power cycling the system after an [extended period of time,](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32529/do-capacitors-automatically-release-their-energy-over-time) and the quality of the capacitors in a laptop/docking station isn't typically very high, there's likely to be no left over charge in any of the capacitors that could cause this anomaly.